# Libgdx stage 'frozen"

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

In my game there is a menu, in this menu, there are 4 tabs and each tab have its own `stage` with tables scrollpanes and buttons (is it a good idea ?)

My problem is that every stage seems "frozen", buttons are not responding and scrollpanes don't scroll

My menu structure :

Menu class

-> render a tab (render `selectedTab`, selectedTab is a Tab object (custom class) that is asigned with a specific tab (Ex: sele shopTab (extend tab class))

```
// menu class
private Tab selectedTab;
private Tab RecipeTab, SellTab, UpgradeTab, ShopTab;

// menu constructor
RecipeTab = new RecipeTab(viewport, sb, itemsdata);
SellTab = new SellTab(viewport, sb, hud);
UpgradeTab = new UpgradeTab(viewport, sb, itemsdata);
ShopTab = new ShopTab(viewport, sb);

selectedTab = RecipeTab;

// render
selectedTab.render(sr, delta);

// on tab change 
public void setSelectedTab(Tab newTab) {selectedTab = newTab;}
setSelectedTab(ShopTab);
```

-> menu contain a navbar to switch tabs (the selected tab is asigned with another tab object)

I don't know if the issue comes from the stages or the actors. even a simple textbutton doesn't work

```
// how my stages are made
// constructor
this.stage = new Stage(viewport, sb); // ExtendViewport (same everywhere), Spritebatch
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.stage);

// render
this.stage.draw();
this.stage.act(delta);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
The answer was simple, there was a conflict with the inputProcessor

i was seting the inputProcessoron each tabs

so i added a `setInputProcessor()` method to the tabs a called it on tab change